# C posix sockets, can't send data from client to server

Tags: c, sockets, posix

I want to make a client and connect it to a server. I know that client process starts running before server so I do connection in infinite loop until it will be accept. Then I want to enter messages to client and send them to server, which will print them on screen. I removed all error detection from code to make it shorter, I know they have to be there. I am trying to do it like this, but server receives nothing and client can't do second connection.

***Server***

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    listen(sockfd, 5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    while (newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,&clilen) >= 0)
    {
        read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
        close(newsockfd);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

***Client***

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    char buffer[256];
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    while (1) {
        while ((connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)  &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)) {
           printf("trying to connect\n");
           sleep(1);
        }
        printf("connected\nplease, enter a message\n");
        scanf("%s", buffer);
        write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once `connect()` fails, there is no guarantee that it can be called again on the same socket. It is usually best to destroy and recreate the socket on each `connect()` attempt.  However, either way, once `connect()` is successful, your client is not closing the connected socket before calling `connect()` again on the next loop iteration.

Comment: If you remove all error handling from the code how can you possibly expect to be able to debug it? This is not a rational strategy. It also isn't an answerable question until you provide an error code, and you can't do that until you put the error handling back; and you can't prove there was no error code until ditto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know just how you've compiled your code but if you had set up the warning flag (`-Wall` in gcc) you would have gotten this warning

```
server.c: In function ‘main’:
server.c:33:44: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
 if (newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,&clilen) >= 0) {
```

Acting by it, I changed, this ..

```
if (newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,&clilen) >= 0) {
```

To .. (notice the extra parentheses)

```
if ((newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,&clilen)) >= 0) {
```

I got no more additional warnings, and the server caught the client's message.

Here is the server I ran while debugging this (This is basically your code with slight alterations)

```
int sockfd, newsockfd;
socklen_t clilen;
char buffer[256];
int nbytes = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
//serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5007);
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));


if (listen(sockfd, 5) <0) { }

clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
if ((newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,&clilen)) >= 0) { 

    while ((nbytes = read(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)))<0) {
        sleep(1);
    }

    printf("client sent: %s", buffer);
}
close(newsockfd);
close(sockfd);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another problem was that we have to create socket each time we do connect in client, like:

```
while (1) {
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    while ((connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)  &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)) {
       printf("trying to connect\n");
       sleep(1);
    }
    printf("connected\nplease, enter a message\n");
    scanf("%s", buffer);
     write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
```

Comment: you should only have one socket and reuse it (unless you want to concurrently connect to more than 1 server point)
you are also not breaking properly from the while loop so you will never have the chance to properly close your sockets. it will hurt your testing because you will have to wait for the OS to free that port after you exit